# Missing the buzzer underneath the cash register in The Salty Oyster

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I know about the hidden door here (in The Salty Oyster in Emporia) from another voxophone recording (and I know Voxophone #57 "One and the Same" is behind the hidden door), but the buzzer doesn't appear beneath the cash register. Did I do something wrong? How can I make it appear?

[image: no button]

Comment: This might be the most unintentionally filthy question title I've ever seen on Arqade. Bravo. Bra-a-a-avo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have to get the recording from the bookstore(library?). It's by the turnstiles that lead to Comstocks home. Then you backtrack.